# Custom data entry in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data, vba, gui

Since VBA support is no longer supported in ArcGIS 10, what is being used out there for custom data entry forms.  I'd like to develop something that is very intuitive (for non-GIS users).

Answer (score 3):

Using Visual Studio and the ArcObjects SDKs you can easily create an ArcGIS Add-in command button. Program the button to launch a form using either WinForms or WPF. This would give you the most control over collecting the custom entry because it makes the entire .NET library available to you.